# Why does spark (Python) gobble my milliseconds?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have timestamps in millisecond format and need to convert them from system time to UTC. Anyways...when doing the transformation spark gobbles my milliseconds and just shows them as zeros.

Short example:

```
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, date_format

spark = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

test = spark.createDataFrame([Row(timestamp = "2018-03-24 14:37:12,133")])
test_2 = test.withColumn('timestamp_2', to_timestamp('timestamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS'))
test_3 = test_2.withColumn('timestamp_3', date_format('timestamp_2', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS'))
test_3.write.option('header', True).csv('something')
```

This will result in:

```
timestamp,timestamp_2,timestamp_3
"2018-03-24 14:37:12,133",2018-03-24T14:37:12.000+01:00,"2018-03-24 14:37:12,000"
```

Can I somehow preserve the milliseconds?

I am using python 3.6.4 and spark version 2.3.2.

Comment: Apparently that's just something `to_timestamp` does. I have no idea why they designed it that way, and neither the [Python docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) nor the [Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) make sense; the Python docs say it's converting to *DateType*, which makes even less sense than what you're seeing, and the Scala docs have weirdly broken English in `to_timestamp`'s description.

Comment: The Scala docs at least say "in seconds", but with no indication of why it would be in seconds when TimestampType has more resolution than that. They also say "Unix timestamp", but that doesn't make much sense either when the output format is TimestampType, not a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Okay. Do you by any chance know a not too ugly solution so that I can convert it to a timestamp? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886772/how-to-convert-a-string-column-with-milliseconds-to-a-timestamp-with-millisecond could be useful.

Comment: What is your SQL backend? This must be a limitation of its timestamp type or something.

Comment: Spark does not utilize any SQL backend...to my understanding.

Comment: According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#TimestampType , spark SQL types do wrap some underlying implementation. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#to_timestamp suggests it's something from Java. I can't find the implementation for `sc._jvm.functions` though to say anything more.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to make it work now. As spark seems to not be able to work correctly with milliseconds, I defined a UDF which uses the `pytz` and `datetime` packages in order to transform the string to `datetime`, change the timezone, and then print the string again.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext

spark = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

def convert_to_utc(timestamp):
    local = pytz.timezone("Arctic/Longyearbyen")
    naive = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
    local_dt = local.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
    utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    return utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]

convert_to_utc_udf = udf(lambda timestamp: convert_to_utc(timestamp), StringType())

test = spark.createDataFrame([Row(timestamp = "2018-03-24 14:37:12,133")])
test_2 = test.withColumn('timestamp_2', convert_to_utc_udf('timestamp'))
test_2.write.option('header', True).csv('something')

#Output:
#timestamp,timestamp_2
#"2018-03-24 14:37:12,133","2018-03-24 13:37:12,133"
```

Inspired by:

[How to convert a string column with milliseconds to a timestamp with milliseconds in Spark 2.1 using Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886772/how-to-convert-a-string-column-with-milliseconds-to-a-timestamp-with-millisecond)

And:

[How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: I don't see how `"2018-03-24 14:37:12,133",2018-03-24T14:37:12.000+01:00,"2018-03-24 14:37:12,000"` is different from before.

Comment: Could you rather explain what you changed and what specifically made it work, and remove irrelevant parts of the code?

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for your feedback. I will remove the unnecessary parts in the answer. Notice however that the last column of the resulting table was the one that was different. `"2018-03-24 14:37:12,133",2018-03-24T14:37:12.000+01:00,"2018-03-24 14:37:12,000","2018-03-24 13:37:12,133"`

Comment: You aren't involving [`pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType) this way -- your resulting data only has strings. So the question proper remains unanswered.

Comment: That is correct. The goal was - as stated - that I want to convert the timestamps from local time to UTC time in spark and want to keep the milliseconds.