# How to create a Dataframe from existing Dataframe and make specific fields as Struct type?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I need to create a DataFrame  from existing DataFrame in which I need to change the schema as well.

I have a DataFrame like:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|Id         |Position   |playerName  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|10125      |Forward    |Messi       |
|10126      |Forward    |Ronaldo     |
|10127      |Midfield   |Xavi        |
|10128      |Midfield   |Neymar      |
```

and I am created this using a case class given below:

```
case class caseClass (
                       Id: Int = "",
                       Position : String = "" ,
                       playerName : String = "" 
                     )
```

Now I need to make both **Playername** and **position** under Struct type.

ie,

I need to create another DataFrame with schema,

> root
>
> |-- Id: int (nullable = true)
>
> |-- playerDetails: struct (nullable = true)
>
> |                               |--playername: string (nullable = true)
>
> |                               |--Position: string (nullable = true)

I did  the following code to create a new dataframe by referring the link
https://medium.com/@mrpowers/adding-structtype-columns-to-spark-dataframes-b44125409803

myschema was

```
  List(
    StructField("Id", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("Position",StringType, true),
    StructField("playerName", StringType,true)
)
```

I tried the following code

```
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  myschema
)
```

but I can't make it happen.

I saw similar question
[Change schema of existing dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50625165/9493078) but I can't understand the solution.

Is there any solution for directly implement StructType  inside the case class? so  that I think I don't need to make own schema for creating struct type values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function "struct" can be used:

```
// data
val playersDF = Seq(
  (10125, "Forward", "Messi"),
  (10126, "Forward", "Ronaldo"),
  (10127, "Midfield", "Xavi"),
  (10128, "Midfield", "Neymar")
).toDF("Id", "Position", "playerName")

// action
val playersStructuredDF = playersDF.select($"Id", struct("playerName", "Position").as("playerDetails"))
// display
playersStructuredDF.printSchema()
playersStructuredDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- playerDetails: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- playerName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Position: string (nullable = true)

+-----+------------------+
|Id   |playerDetails     |
+-----+------------------+
|10125|[Messi, Forward]  |
|10126|[Ronaldo, Forward]|
|10127|[Xavi, Midfield]  |
|10128|[Neymar, Midfield]|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Your solution is good,But in my case

_val inputFile = spark.read.textFile("C:\\Users\\adarsh.k\\Downloads\\players.txt")
    inputFile.map ( lines => {
      val Id = extractFun(lines , """regex""" )
      val position= extractFun(lines, """regex""")
      val playerName = extractFun(lines , """regex""" )
caseClass (Id, position,playerName)
    }).toDF()_
I am taking vlaues to case class like this.and I have a function to extract the data using REGEX

Comment: When using this solution I got an error that

**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Id`' given input columns: [value];;**

Comment: Looks like something wrong with extraction from original data to case class, guess, this is out of scope of original question.

Comment: Sorry, It was actually my mistake.

I didn't took the **inputFile.map** as a dataframe.

When i tried

**val newData=inputFile.map ( lines => {**
**........}**

It worked For me....Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now I am getting like

[Messi, Forward]

can i get it like 

**[Messi:Forward]**

like key-value pair??

Comment: From original dataframe:
playersDF.select($"Id", concat_ws(":", $"Position", $"playerName"))