# spark jdbc api can't use built-in function

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark-sql, impala

I want to get subquery from impala table as one dataset.

**Code like this:**

```
String subQuery = "(select to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(now())) as ts from my_table) t"
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().jdbc(myImpalaUrl, subQuery, prop);
```

**But result is error:**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: [Cloudera][JDBC](10140) Error converting value to Timestamp.
```

I can use `unix_timestamp` function,but `to_timestmap` failed, why?

I found code in `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBC.compute()` exists some problem:

```
sqlText = s"SELECT $columnList FROM ${options.table} $myWhereClause"
```

`$columList` contains `"` like `"col_name"` , when I delete `"` it work fine.

Comment: Isn't `now()` already a timestamp?

Comment: I just use `now()`  as  example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844144/better-way-to-convert-a-string-field-into-timestamp-in-spark might be useful

Comment: thanks,I solved this problem by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by add dialect, default dialect will add `""` to column name,

```
 JdbcDialect ImpalaDialect = new JdbcDialect(){
        @Override
        public boolean canHandle(String url) {
            return url.startsWith("jdbc:impala") || url.contains("impala");
        }
        @Override
        public String quoteIdentifier(String colName) {
            return colName;
        }
    };

    JdbcDialects.registerDialect(ImpalaDialect);
```