# Spark Dataframe: Convert bigint to timestamp

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Dataframe with a bigint column. How to convert a bigint column to timestamp in scala spark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **`from_unixtime/to_timestamp`** function in spark to convert `Bigint` column to `timestamp`.

***Example:***

```
spark.sql("select timestamp(from_unixtime(1563853753,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as ts").show(false)
+-------------------+
|ts                 |
+-------------------+
|2019-07-22 22:49:13|
+-------------------+
```

**(or)**

```
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(1563853753) as ts").show(false)
+-------------------+
|ts                 |
+-------------------+
|2019-07-22 22:49:13|
+-------------------+
```

***Schema*:**

```
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(1563853753) as ts").printSchema
root
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844144/better-way-to-convert-a-string-field-into-timestamp-in-spark) link for more details regards to converting different formats of timestamps in spark.

Comment: Is there a command to convert the column? Say I have a df with a column named 'ts' and I want that column to be converted from bigint to date time, how to do that?