# to_timestamp() in pyspark giving null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying the following simple transformation.

```
data = [["06/15/2020 14:04:04]]
cols = ["date"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,cols)

df = df.withColumn("datetime",F.to_timestamp(F.col("date"),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS))
df.show()
```

But this gives me an error "All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y, Please use the SQL function EXTRACT instead"

I want to format the data into that date format and convert it to timestamp.

Comment: What is `HH24:MI:` for?

Comment: I want the date to be in 24 hours format. Let me know the correct way if this is wrong way of defining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to convert a string field into timestamp in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844144/better-way-to-convert-a-string-field-into-timestamp-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this format - `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'`

Check [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) page for all datetime format related details.

```
df = df.withColumn("datetime",to_timestamp(col("date"),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
df.show()

+-------------------+-------------------+
|               date|           datetime|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|06/15/2020 14:04:04|2020-06-15 14:04:04|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The different elements of the timestamp pattern are explained in Spark's [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). Note that Spark parses timestamps utilising Java's [SimpleTimeFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which uses a somewhat confusing set of format symbols. The symbol matching the hour in 24hrs representation is simply `H` with no digital suffixes. The minutes are `m` and not `M` which is for the month. The year is matched by `y` and not by `Y` which is for week year. Week years are unsupported hence the message you're getting.

In your case, the proper format should be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.